# Is there any way to dump the Data Usage log through the ADB shell?

Tags: adb, logging, data-monitoring, mobile-data

The reason I would need to dump these data is because in smalls display (S5301) doesn't fit everything and data is cut. I couldn't do anything to move that graphic.

Look,

[image]

I've searched in Google but without success.

Comment: This is not quite what you asked, but does turning the device to landscape orientation help?

Comment: If not: is the device rooted?

Comment: Landscape orientation helped to guess.

Comment: No root. Would it be only possible having it rooted? I was curious anyway.